# ¿Cómo hago arreglos con claves en C#, además de insertar dentro más arrays?

Tags: javascript, c#, array

Hace poco estoy aprendiendo C# y me pasa de que tengo que hacer en C# lo que en Javascript es equivalente a:

```
var input = [
    {in:[1.7,56,38], out:1},
    {in:[1.72,63,41], out:0},
    {in:[1.6,50,36], out:1},
    {in:[1.7,63,41], out:0},
    {in:[1.74,66,42], out:0},
    {in:[1.58,55,35], out:1},
    {in:[1.83,80,45], out:0},
    {in:[1.65,54,36], out:1}
];
```

Pero no se cómo hacerlo y **necesito la mayor cantidad de información sobre esto**, además que sea especifica. Si alguien me puede ayudar se lo agradezco de antemano.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! eso no es un arreglo bidimensional (lo que se conoce como matriz) eso es una construccion propia de js, que no es mas que un arreglo que contiene objetos.. de bidimensional no tiene nada.

Comment: Hay algo que haga que no puedas usar una lista genérica, o un diccionario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrias resolverlo con `class` y `List<>` o `arrays`, entonces creas una clase como ser

```
 public class dato{
     public List<decimal> in {get;set;}
     public int out {get;set;}
 }
```

lo usas de esta forma

```
var input = new dato[] {
   new dato() { @in = new[] {1.7m,56,38}, @out= 1 },
   new dato() { @in = new[] {1.72m,63,41}, @out= 0 },
   //resto
};
```

Nota: los @ en las propiedades `in` y `out` se deben poner porque son palabras reservadas del lenguaje